# Travel planner app that allows to save routes, and open each on Google Maps Directions

Tags: planning, travel

I'm looking for a simple travel planner app (web/mobile), that should allow 3 things:

1. Enter multiple dates.
2. For each date, enter multiple travel events. A "travel event" should have a start and an end address, and a start hour.
3. When clicking a travel event, open Google Maps Directions (all travel options included) for it.

I looked into TripIt app and tried using its Navigator functionality to do the above, but unfortunately, I get "no results found". I'm therefore looking for other recommendations.

Any suggestions?